# How do I download a TED video?

Tags: video, download

Does anyone have a method of downloading a video from [TED](http://www.ted.com/)? I tried the [techniques](https://superuser.com/questions/107343/how-can-i-download-a-flash-video-from-a-website) here, but they didn't work.

Comment: PS. Is this a web apps question, or is it better to ask on SuperUser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TED videos can be downloaded directly from their website:

[image]

You can also get it through their [RSS feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/tedtalks_video) if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The videos on TED can be downloaded directly from the website. But if you want to [download videos from TED](http://www.streamingmediarecorder.com/download-videos-from-ted.html) in batch, use a streaming video downloader will be more effcient. I use Video download capture to do this job. You can have a try, I think this program won’t let you down.

Answer (score 1):

[ted2mkv](https://github.com/oxplot/ted2mkv) downloads TED videos and all their subtitles and creates a standalone (with subtitles embedded) mkv file.

Answer (score -1):

you could also look into this : http://obinshah.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/ted-v3-0-the-tedinator/

it downloads subtitles too alongwith different video quality